# MYSQL - Select com a Coluna Data Formatada com Convert

Tags: mysql

Tenho a tabela(tbl) com o seguinte campo

> id, date

*date* é um campo varchar, que tem datas no seguinte formato: "*dd/mm/yyyy*"

Quero fazer um *SELECT*, que seja mostrado a data no formato ANSI "*yyyy-mm-dd*".

Pensei que a seguinte instrução funcionária, mas nao:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, date, 103) FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa tratar como string, similar a:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data FROM tbl
```

Origem: [MySQL date format DD/MM/YYYY select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)